# ! Undefined control sequence. \bibrangedash ->\bibendash

Tags: biblatex, babel, biber

This code exemplifies the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,catalan]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}

@article{cerf_rfc_2007,
    title = {{RFC} 4838, delay-tolerant networking architecture},
    volume = {2},
    number = {4},
    journal = {{IRTF} {DTN} Research Group},
    author = {Cerf, V and Burleigh, S and Hooke, A and Torgerson, L and Durst, R and Scott, K and Fall, K and Weiss, H},
    year = {2007},
    pages = {6}
}

@article{burleigh2003delay,
  title={Delay-tolerant networking: an approach to interplanetary internet},
  author={Burleigh, Scott and Hooke, Adrian and Torgerson, Leigh and Fall, Kevin and Cerf, Vint and Durst, Bob and Scott, Keith and Weiss, Howard},
  journal={Communications Magazine, IEEE},
  volume={41},
  number={6},
  pages={128--136},
  year={2003},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{./example.bib}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{}
cite\cite{cerf_rfc_2007}, cite2\cite{burleigh2003delay}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The Undefined control sequence error appears when printing the bibliography with \printbibliography. Seem to be a problem with the catalan support of biber or bilbaltex, if I change the babel language to English all works correctly.

EDIT: Added MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I suggest you use the `filecontents` package to include a BibTeX entry that contains `\bibrangedash` and/or `\bibendash`.

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Do you use an updated system?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm using Mactex 2011 completely updated.

Comment: Are you sure it is updated? I had `biblatex 2.5` and `biber 1.5` and got the same error. But after (just now) updating to `biblatex 2.6` and `biber 1.6` the problem has vanished...

Comment: yep, you are right, I have version 2.5 and 1.5 installed. tlmgr and Tex Live utility doesn't show any update, I'll have to update manually.

Comment: Catalan support was improved in 2.6 and this is only available with the TL 2013 pretest installer at the moment as TL 2012 was frozen before 2.6 was released.

Comment: mmh ok. i was wrong I have Mactex 2012. But I think there is no Mactex 2013, can I update manually anyway?

Comment: ok, I found MacTex 2013 :) It's downlaoding, I hope when it's installed, all will be fixed! how I mark the question as ansewerd?